# Different languages for devkitPPC (Wii) development

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages, devkitpro

[devkitpro](http://devkitpro.org/) has been pretty great for development so far. However, I was wondering if there were any other libraries, either independent or based on devkitpro, that would incorporate other languages for me to explore

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wii.py`: Python extension for Wii. Unfortunately lacking sufficient documentation (like most open-source community projects), but still functional nonetheless.

**Reference**: https://github.com/icefire/Wii.py

`luafwii`: Lua player for Wii. Since it's Lua, this is best suited for projects that involve a C base but incorporate plugins or scripts on top. Although Lua includes a built-in garbage collector, this library also includes explicit freeing for images and sounds.

**Reference**: http://luafwii.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Enjoy and good luck!